# Ios app crashses in offline mode with flutter firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, persistence

I have created a flutter app to get and save data on firebase Realtime database
my app's simple functionality is user need signup then he/she can upload photos and notes(text data) through the app
My app is works fine in online and as well as in offline mode in Android device
and IOS device it works fine in online mode  but
----------->"user comes with offline mode App crashes in IOS device only "<-----------

```
     FirebaseApp.configure() 
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

i have added this two line in AppDelegateFile but it not working